# Proof $|\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!} - (1+z/n)^n| \leq \frac{|z|^2}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \frac{|z|^k}{k!}$

Tags: analysis, inequality, proof-writing

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that

$$|\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!} - (1+z/n)^n| \leq \frac{|z|^2}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \frac{|z|^k}{k!}$$

How can one prove that?

I was able to prove that $|\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!} - (1+\frac{z}{n})^n \leq \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{|z|^k}{k!} + (1 + \frac{|z|}{n})^n$ using the Triangle Inequality and the Binomial Theorem, but this doesn't help since $\big( 1+ \frac{|z|}{n}\big)^n > 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need any special knowledge here, it's enough to expand the brackets in the LHS using the binomial theorem. It equals $\Bigl|\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{z^k}{k!}\bigl( 1-\frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k} \bigl)\Bigl|$. Because terms with $k=0$ and $1$ vanish, it's sufficient to prove the inequality
$$ \frac{|z|^k}{k!}\Bigl( 1-\frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k} \Bigl) \, \le\, \frac{|z|^k}{n\cdot{}(k-2)!}$$ for each $k=2..n$.

Indeed, $$1-\frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k} = 1-\frac{n\cdot{}(n-1)\cdot{}\ldots\cdot{}(n-k+1)}{n^k} = \frac{n^{k}-n\cdot{}\ldots\cdot{}(n-k+1)}{n^{k}} \le \frac{n^k-n^{k-1}\cdot{}(n-k+1)}{n^{k}} = \frac{n^{k-1}(k-1)}{n^{k}}=\frac{k-1}{n} \le \frac{(k-1)!}{n\cdot{}(k-2)!}\le \frac{k!}{n\cdot{}(k-2)!}$$

and multiplying opposite sides of this inequality by $\frac{|z|^k}{k!}$ gives us the desired inequality.

Comment: If you stop at the $\frac{k-1}{n}$ step, you get a better inequality.